# Android TabLayout and ViewPager Fragment using RxJava

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, rx-java, android-tablayout

Let's say that I have a ViewPager that will have 2 Fragments. From those Fragments, I create a PublishSubject which I would like to subscribe to within the MainActivity. However, the issue is during the onCreate(), I would not be able to grab that specific PublishSubject from the Fragment since it seems like it hasn't been created yet. Therefore, I end up with an NPE if I tried to make a subscription for it.

Is there a way to pass the PublishSubject once the Fragment is created by the ViewPager to the MainActivity? Or should I be trying to do something else instead. I've tried looking through other issues, but I couldn't find anything that is similar with something like this.

Some Code to illustrate what I mean:

Fragment

```
public class ExampleFragment extends Fragment {
    PublishSubject<SomeObject> mPublishSubject = PublishSubject.create();

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstance){
          // Regular fragment stuff here
    }

    public PublishSubject<SomeObject> getPublishSubject() {
        return mPublishSubject;
    }
}
```

ViewPager

```
public class ExamplePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0: 
                return new ExampleFragment();
            case 1:
                return new SomeOtherFragment();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private PublishSubject<SomeObject> mSubjectFromTheFragment;
    private ExamplePagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("tab1"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("tab2"));
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        mPagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);

        // Set listener
        mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {

            // Code to implement the methods
        });

        // When or where do I set PublishSubject
        mPublishSubject = ?

        // The subscription
        mPublishSubject.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(/** Some new Action1<> etc. **/ )
    }

}
```

Any help or pointing me to some kind of direction is really appreciated!

Comment: I think I was able to find a work-around for this issue. Instead of calling a PublishSubject.create() in the Fragment, you can do that operation within the PagerAdapter and set that specific PublishSubject when creating the Fragment. However, is this the best way to handle a situation like this?

Comment: What you want to achieve with this? Do you want to have a communication from fragment to MainActivity?

Comment: So the Fragment will display a RecyclerView where calling mPublishSubject.onNext(SomeObject) would add onto the RecyclerView.